# Solving an equation by fixed point theorem !?

Tags: solution-verification, normed-spaces, fixed-point-theorems, complete-spaces

Let $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ be a normed space with  $\|(x, y)\|_{1}=|x|+|y|$
and  $f: \mathbb{R}^{2} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{2}$ defined by :
$$
f(x, y)=\left(\frac{1}{4} \sin (x+y), 1+\frac{2}{3} \arctan (x-y)\right)
$$

1. Show that there exists $k \in] 0,1\left[\right.$ such that, for all  $(x, y),\left(x^{\prime}, y^{\prime}\right) \in \mathbb{R}^{2},$ we have
   $$
   \left\|f(x, y)-f\left(x^{\prime}, y^{\prime}\right)\right\|_{1} \leq k\left\|(x, y)-\left(x^{\prime}, y^{\prime}\right)\right\|_{1}
   $$
2. Deduce that
   $$
   \left\{\begin{aligned}
   \frac{1}{4} \sin (x+y) &=x \\
   1+\frac{2}{3} \arctan (x-y) &=y
   \end{aligned}\right.
   $$
   admits a unique solution in  $\mathbb{R}^{2}$.
3. can we use the same method using the norm $\|.\|_{\infty}$  instead of $\|\cdot\|_{1}$ ?

**My attempt :**

1. By using the mean value theorem, for all $(u, v) \in \mathbb{R}^{2},$ we have
   $$
   |\sin (u)-\sin (v)| \leq|u-v| \text { et }|\arctan (u)-\arctan (v)| \leq|u-v|
   $$
   so,
   $$
   \begin{aligned}
   \left\|f(x, y)-f\left(x^{\prime}, y^{\prime}\right)\right\|_{1} & \leq \frac{1}{4}\left|\sin (x+y)-\sin \left(x^{\prime}+y^{\prime}\right)\right|+\frac{2}{3}\left|\arctan (x-y)-\arctan \left(x^{\prime}-y^{\prime}\right)\right| \\
   & \leq \frac{1}{4}\left|(x+y)-\left(x^{\prime}+y^{\prime}\right)\right|+\frac{2}{3}\left|(x-y)-\left(x^{\prime}-y^{\prime}\right)\right| \\
   & \leq \frac{1}{4}\left|\left(x-x^{\prime}\right)+\left(y-y^{\prime}\right)\right|+\frac{2}{3}\left|\left(x-x^{\prime}\right)-\left(y-y^{\prime}\right)\right| \\
   & \leq\left(\frac{1}{4}+\frac{2}{3}\right)\left(\left|x-x^{\prime}\right|+\left|y-y^{\prime}\right|\right) \\
   & \leq \frac{11}{12}\left\|(x, y)-\left(x^{\prime}, y^{\prime}\right)\right\|_{1}
   \end{aligned}
   $$
2. The function $f$ is contactant, and  $(\mathbb{R}^{2},\|.\|_{1})$ is a Banach space. According to the fixed point theorem, there exists a unique couple $(x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^{2}$ such that  $(x, y)=f(x, y) .$ In other words, the system admits a unique solution.
3. I got stuck here, so any help is appreciated !